# Store subscription details for users in Wordpress

Tags: users, user-meta

I want to store subscription details of several category for users. how to store this to wp database. i am beginner to wordpress.

whether i want to create new table or can i use

meta ,taxonomy

or some thing?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe start searching for plugins like [Wishlist-Member](http://member.wishlistproducts.com/), its description will give you the jargon and wordpress-specific ideas you'll need to better refine your search and move forward in your solution.

Comment: patently false accusation! I have no affiliations. The question here is asking for some direction among a myriad of possibilities.  Wordpress has jargon which a new user can only get by reading up on solutions and experimenting. My answer tells the user to look for a better way to ask his question.  You, I think, have wrongly assumed that coz I'm new and i mention some link or other I am spamming.